# How to make Execute JavaScript of RobotFramework's keyword return a value

Tags: javascript, robotframework

**How to make Execute JavaScript of RobotFramework return a value**

I need the text of a class element be returned using javascript code to a variable within RF. I have tried the following code but I get     **${search_result} = None**. It's not returning the text within the element selected.

```
:FOR    ${index}                    IN RANGE                            0   23
\  ${search_result} =             Execute JavaScript                  floatMaster.querySelectorAll('#gContact_searcResultshWindow .gContactDetailClientListDiv .gContactListName')[${index}].innerText
```

I have also tried below but I just get **JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Unexpected number**

```
${search_result} =              Execute JavaScript                   function myFunction(${index}) {return floatMaster.querySelectorAll('#gContact_searcResultshWindow .gContactDetailClientListDiv .gContactListName')[${index}].innerText}()
```

The reason of the for loop is that the javascript locator has multiple results and I want to make sure each of them carry a specific text. I have a "should contain" command at the end of the loop.

[image: javascript locator result from browser console]

When I try the javascript locator command with the index in browser console, I get a value just fine.
[image]

I am also aware of the Execute Async JavaScript command but it seems complicated and I don't understand how it works. Somebody help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
${search_result}=    Execute JavaScript    return floatMaster.querySelectorAll('#gContact_searcResultshWindow .gContactDetailClientListDiv .gContactListName')[${index}].innerText
```